# What makes this off-topic?

Tags: support, scope, close-reasons, closed-questions

Sorry, but I'm new to Seasoned Advice, so please be a bit nicer.

I answered [a question which seems like an on-topic question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/115778/rice-recipe-for-instant-pot-lux-5-quart), and I recently found out that it got closed as off-topic. The reason I thought it was on-topic is because it's a cooking question, and I even answered it the best way I could think possible.

Why is the question closed as off-topic?

Comment: It is not actually off topic, it is a question whose topic is OK but its kind does not work on the site. I recently wrote an answer which may help you understand your confusion: https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3672/4638. See also our Help center, specifically https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: The question being discussed could’ve had a few comments asking them what recipe they were using and how it went wrong, so we could tell them how to fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be other reasons, but the one that jumps right out is:

> suggest a good recipe

Asking for recipes is considered "off-topic", as it can generate too many responses, none of which can be definitively declared as the one right answer.

Similarly, "good" is considered "off-topic" as whether something is good is a matter of opinion, and again there is no one right answer.

It would be better to say something like:

- Using the XXX pressure cooker, I follow this recipe: YYY, but the result is too ZZZ.
- What am I doing wrong?

Good questions give facts and ask for facts.

Comment: makes sense! I'm learning more about this site's scope now.

Comment: @DerrickWilliams, you should also know that accepting an answer (i.e. the check mark you just selected) shouldn't normally be done for at least 24 hours after the question has been asked.  This gives everyone around the world a chance to see and answer the question.  And once a question has been marked as accepted, many people won't bother to read the question as they know it already has an excellent answer.  This means that you might now miss out on an answer that is a lot better than mine.

Comment: oh, I see. well, it's close to sleeping time for me, so if I have a left out question, I guess anyone can take a look at the question and answer it. I usually take naps, so that's also gonna give them a better chance of solving the question.

Comment: This is the reason why "give me a list" is also off-topic.  It's not that we don't want to answer those things, it's that there's no good way to have a definitive answer.